# After updating Android studio to 2.2.3, it's asking me to migrate my project to Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating, it's asking me to migrate my project to Gradle. Problem is, my project was initially created in Android Studio and was already using the Gradle build system. The instructions provided for migrating only specify importing a project from intelliJ. As a result of it not using Gradle, I am getting a number of can't resolve method errors on calls searching for global methods such as getString().

Comment: Did you try clean and build? You may try gradle sync before that too.

Comment: you can't clean and build if it's not using the Gradle system